# How disable conversion from pug to html in pug-loader?

Tags: web, webpack, pug

Or how load image from pug, without `pug-loader`?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? Why do you want do disable Pug compilation with the `pug-loader`? If you want to only include images in your Webpack process, why not use some other module (such as `file-loader`) that focuses only on that scenario?

Comment: hi! of course. i have server on adonis framework and template language in this i dont like. .edge-file, syntax like this: {{ some_varible }} + pug file look much "cleaner". Of course, i can use structure like this: | {{ some_var }} but it's too ugly and uncomfortable. I did not really understand how to use fillet loader: if i use: "test: /\.pug/ use: [ { loader: 'file-loader',}]" - this is dont work. and I need to "import" in pug file too processed. if I'm wrong and pug do not use for dynamic rendering please, follow me.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration, but I'm not sure I understand your question, yet. Why exactly do you not want to compile Pug into HTML? That's the only real use case it was designed for... If you want to dynamically change template code on the client, MVC frameworks like React (together with Meteor) might be more what you're looking for

Comment: Yes, I thought about it (more precisely about vue ssr). And what about pug it does not use it for dynamic compilation?

Comment: Well, not really, at least to my knowledge. It's excellent for server-side templating, but anything going hybrid (so also having a frontend rendering part) needs another framework to work. I've seen both Vue and Angular being used in combination with Pug syntax, and I can definitely recommend using the Pug syntax for those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created this Webpack loader for precisely this use case.  You will of course have to use Webpack to use this, but let me know if this helps you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug-asset-loader